# How to pass data back from a form that has been previously AJAX called?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, session

So, I'm trying to code a button that pops up a modal which text has been AJAX called from another php file. The thing is within the modal there is an input and I need to pass the input value to the original URL so it can be submitted along with other variables when the user clicks OK in the modal.

I've tried the code below and all the AJAX calls work, however the input variable (selected_shares) passes empty. I would deeply appreciate your kind help.

ASSETS_TABLE.PHP

```
    <?php
    $userLoggedIn = $_SESSION['username'];
    $compe = $_SESSION["comp"];
    $selected_shares = $_GET["selected_shares"];
    ?>

    <table>              
        <tbody>

          <?php

            $assets_query = mysqli_query($con1, "SELECT * FROM assets WHERE username='$userLoggedIn' AND competition='$compe'");
            $assets_query_r = mysqli_fetch_array($assets_query);

                foreach($assets_query as $assets_query_r) {
                                                          ?>

                      <tr>
                      <td><?= $assets_query_r['Item'] ?></td>
                      <td><button id="<?= $assets_query_r['Item'] ?>" data-toggle = "modal" data-target = "#myModal5" onclick="showDetails(this)">
                      </button></td>
                      </tr>

                      <?php
                       } ?>

                      </tbody>
                      </table>


    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class = "modal fade" id = "myModal5" tabindex = "-1" role = "dialog"
   aria-labelledby = "myModalLabel" aria-hidden = "true" data-backdrop="false" style="" >

   <div class = "modal-dialog">
      <div class = "modal-content">

         <div class = "modal-header">
           <h4 class = "modal-title" id = "myModalLabel">
              Sale order
           </h4>


            <button type = "button" class = "close" data-dismiss = "modal" aria-hidden = "true" style="background-color: transparent; margin-top: -20px; float: right; color: #4d4646; width: 10px; height: 10px;">
                  &times;
            </button>


         </div>

         <div class = "modal-body">
            <p><span id="value5" style="color:black;"></span></p>
         </div>
         <div class = "modal-footer">
                     <button type = "button" id="modal_yes_btn5" class = "btn btn-primary" style="width: 80px; height: 40px;" onclick="yesBtnFunction5()">
                        Ok
                     </button>

                     <button type = "button" class = "btn btn-default" data-dismiss = "modal" id="modal_no_btn5" style="width: 80px; height: 40px;" onclick="noBtnFunction()">
                        Close
                     </button>


                  </div>

               </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
            </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->



</div>
    <!-- /.modal -->

    <script>

    function showDetails(button) {

    window.name = button.id;
    var username = "<?php echo $userLoggedIn; ?>";
    var competition = "<?php echo $compe; ?>";

      $.get('customer.php', {"name": name, "username": username, "competition": competition}, function(data){ $("#value5").html(data); $("#modal_yes_btn5").prop('disabled', false);}, 'html' );

    }

    function yesBtnFunction(){

      var username = "<?php echo $userLoggedIn; ?>";
      var competition = "<?php echo $compe; ?>";
      var selected_shares = "<?php echo $selected_shares; ?>";

      $.ajax({
      url: "data_loader.php",
      method: "GET",
      data: {"username": username, "competition": competition, "selected_shares": selected_shares},
      success:

      function(response){
        $("#value5").text(response);
        $("#modal_yes_btn5").prop('disabled', true);
      }
      });
      }
     </script>
```

CUSTOMER.PHP

```
<?php
  $name = $_GET["name"];
  $username = $_GET["username"];
  $competition = $_GET["competition"];

  echo "Data: " . $name . $username . $competition . " Now type a number:";
    ?>
  <br>
  <input id="numberinput" type="text" style="width:100px; "value="0"> </input>

  <script>

      $('#numberinput').on("input paste keyup", function( event ) {

          selected_shares = $(this).val();
          var selected_shares = selected_shares;

          $.ajax({
          url: "assets_table.php",
          method: "GET",
          data: {"selected_shares": selected_shares},
          success: function(response){
             $('#myModal5').on('shown.bs.modal', showDetails); 
          }
          });

    }

      </script>
```

Comment: set the value on success of ajax in the modal

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find the `#value5` element in your HTML, and I think you`re trying to code in JavaScript with the PHP thinking.

Javascript run on client side, so you need to think in the browser flow. If you want to load a modal content from another page the process should be like:

```
<div id="my-modal"> nothing </div>
```

And than:

```
<script>
  $.get('somewhere', function(c) {
     //At this point you`re creating new HTML on the browser
     //And after that you can bind events on the new elements created
     $('#my-modal').html(c); 
     $("#my-button-returned-from-ajax").on('click', doSomething);
  }, 'HTML')
</script>
```

This is a small snippet for what you want to do, it`s not the only and not even close the better way to do it.

Comment: Hi Lucas, many thanks for your input. I have edited the code to make things more clear and added the modal part. Does your response remain the same?

Comment: HI @chancar the #guradio it's also a good tip, you should use modal on the open event to run the showDetails function.

$('#myModal5').on('shown.bs.modal', showDetails) ;

With this simple action, you have the guarantee that the ajax will not try to bind the returned HTML on a not opened modal (Bootstrap recreate the HTML, so you loose your bind.

Comment: Sorry @Lucas, I'm not sure I understand. Do you mean like I edited the code?

Comment: @chancar in your code the ajax can be running before the modal be created, you need to make sure the ajax only run after.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I fixed by using this code instead:

```
$.get('customer.php', {"name": name, "username": username, "competition": competition}, function(data){ $("#value5").html(data); $("#modal_yes_btn5").prop('disabled', false); return selected_shares; var selected_shares = selected_shares;}, 'html' );
```